Are Ordinals and Inscriptions on-topic?
In the past, there was broad support for narrowing the topic of Bitcoin SE to “technologies that are applicable to supporting the bitcoin currency, in the past, present, or future”.
While it seems obvious to me that BRC20 tokens are off-topic, since we’ve previously also treated other cryptocurrencies built on colored coin projects such as Omni as off-topic, it doesn’t seem obvious to me whether ordinals and Inscriptions are on-topic or off-topic here. There have been some questions asked and answered, but the topic seems to have gotten a tepid reception.
Please weigh in on how we should treat questions about Ordinals and/or Inscriptions. Are they on-topic or off-topic? On what grounds are you arguing either position? Where’s the border between on-topic and off-topic? What criteria are we using to assess whether to keep open or close such topics?

If Murch is not sure Ordinals are off topic, then they are on topic.

@Mercedes -  you should add an answer here so your opinion can be discussed and voted up or down.

tl;dr: How to Ordinal = off topic. Sky falling because Ordinals = on-topic.
Although I find Ordinals and Inscriptions interesting, I am certain that is insufficient grounds for suggesting they be made on-topic. I think questions about making or using Ordinals Inscriptions, or how to mint or transfer a BRC-20 token, should be off-topic if this site is to be consistent about it's Bitcoin-only policy.
I think there is some merit in accepting questions relating to Ordinals impact on the performance and sustainability of the Bitcoin network and currency.

Per the highly upvoted answers on Proposal: Narrow topic of Bitcoin.Stackexchange to questions applicable to Bitcoin, this site should collect questions about technologies that are applicable to supporting the bitcoin currency, in the past, present, or future.
After they have been around for almost a year:

Inscriptions appear to have no relation to the bitcoin currency, they merely use the Bitcoin network and blockchain as a publication mechanism. I consider inscriptions off-topic.
Ordinals are a social convention how to keep track of specific satoshis. This convention is completely out-of-band and appears to be irrelevant to the bitcoin currency. I would therefore also consider ordinals off-topic on this site.

Questions about e.g. bitcoin script, blockchain footprint, or mempool behavior might still be on-topic even if they are caused or related to ordinals or inscriptions.

Agreed.  I consider inscriptions and ordinals off-topic, and indeed any future tech that is not about Bitcoin itself would be off topic.  The bar here should be "does this question and any potential answer help the bitcoin.se audience understand Bitcoin and the bitcoin network."
